# function returning released objects

Tags: iphone

I have made a custom singleton class with an nsmutabledictionary as a property.I set and retrieve values in this class through two methods

```
-(void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    if(!object||object==nil)
    {

        return;
    }
    [self.dict setObject:[object retain] forKey:key];   
}
```

and objectForKey

```
-(id)objectForKey:(NSString*)key
{

    id obj=[self.dict objectForKey:key];
    return obj;
}
```

The reason i do this is that while i save and retrieving values from nsuserdefaults in iterative methods(10000 loops or higher) the code is much slower.Hence i built a class mimicing the functionality of  nsuserdefaults .  The problem is that sometimes the values returned from this class is already released.As a result the code crashes ,Is there any further validations we can make so that this class returns only non released objects

Comment: no need to retain the object explicitly by `[object retain]`. it will automatically be retained when added to dictionary. coming to original problem, it does not seems like there is any other problem with ur code that u have shared...

Comment: ya but since it is returning zombie(released) values i tried by giving an extra retain to all objects in the dictionary but still it is not working

Comment: u need to check your `dict` variable when you receive a NSZombie crash. The problem might be with the `dict' variable being released

Comment: Use ARC, seriously. This would remove the need for all of this junk. You loose NOTHING by having ARC enabled in your project.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  actually there are some third party libraries in my code that are not based on ARC,right now i am not so proficient as to make changes in that libraries for implementing ARC,i had tried  once to implement ARC in my project,but xcode reports a lot of changes to be made before implementing it

Comment: You can enable ARC to all the project but disable it in some files with the -fno-obj-arc compiler flag on them